# What does the name Chacha (チャチャ) mean?

Tags: meaning, names

I always wondered about the meaning of this name in Japanese, but couldn't find much on Google. Can someone tell me what it means?

UPDATE: 茶々{ちゃちゃ} was a concubine to [Toyotomi Hideyoshi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyotomi_Hideyoshi) in the [Sengoku Period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sengoku_period). I found the info [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yodo-dono).

Additionally, I found that a fictional character form the Japanese manga series Maken-Ki is named Akaza Chacha (藜 チャチャ). Info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maken-ki

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but it doesn't really look like a Japanese name.  Is it the name of a fictional character?

Comment: So it seems. Although, according to history, the name of Yodo-dono, cocubine of Toyotomi Hideyoshi in her youth was Cha-cha. So it may be a true name, just unusual though

Comment: Just as an update, in that case the japanese characters are (茶々) or so I read.

Comment: @Xanathos Can you please update the question with all that additional information? All the important context information should be in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: You also have to tell us where you found the name in order to guess at its meaning, whether it's part of historical fiction, a video game, a contemporary novel, ...

Comment: There is more info. about her real name on the Japanese wiki page [淀殿](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B7%80%E6%AE%BF), as follows:[本名は 浅井 茶々（あざい ちゃちゃ）および浅井 菊子（あざい きくこ）。] I don't know the origin of 茶々, but I found a meaning [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E8%8C%B6%E3%80%85/m0u/) that is someone who interrupts others or butts in on conversations. Don't know if that is historically related to her name though.

Comment: Yodo-dono is not her actual name. English wiki BASICALLY misunderstands common names (title) of Japanese historical figures as their actual name and their actual names as their youth name.

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for since you mention it's a name, but when you say 茶々を入れる, it means to tease, to make fun of.

Comment: Yes, so it seems. At least everything points to that. Anyway, give the answer below, and I'll give it the check.

Comment: Is this "Cha-cha" name question from "Curb your enthusiasm"?

Answer (score 1):

Chacha was lady Yodo's childhood name, eldest daughter of Oichi, Oda Nobunaga's sister. Trying to find the meaning myself.. That first kanji looks like it's from Ocha, which is tea... But that's only the reach of my amateur "otaku Japanese"... I can read hiragana and katakana, but I only know a few dozen kanji, probably less than 100, which is not a lot. >_<